# How to use the AssociationField with a ManyToMany relationship in EasyAdmin 4?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, easyadmin

I created an Artist Entity and an User Entity in Symfony 6. Both entities have a ManyToMany relationship, so a join table was created.

User Entity

```
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'author', targetEntity: Comment::class)]
    private $comments;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Artist::class, inversedBy: 'users')]
    private $artists;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->artists = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Artist Entity

```
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: User::class, mappedBy: 'artists')]
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->albums = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->concerts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

In EasyAdmin, in the ArtistCrudController, I want to relate both tables. But they don't have foreign keys. The foreign keys are in the join table (user_artist), so the AssociationField can't work. How could I relate two entities in a CrudController?

Comment: What are you trying to do, what kind of form or input do you want ? Is it a collection type, a simple select (entity type) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use CollectionType instead of AssociationType in a ManyToMany relationship

https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields/CollectionField.html